# How to use PLINQ for IO-bound tasks?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, concurrency

According to the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1812657/why-does-plinq-uses-only-two-threads), there is no way to effectively use LINQ for IO bound tasks. Is there a way to gain better control, or is LINQ just not suited for such tasks?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't agree with your conclusion. In the other question, Luke stated that:

> From the MSDN documentation: "Degree
>   of parallelism is the maximum number
>   of concurrently executing tasks that
>   will be used to process the query".
>   **WithDegreeOfParallelism is just a hint
>   that PLINQ should use no more than n
>   threads.**

The fact that Plinq only decides to use two threads for your code instead of ten *doesn't mean that it is unsuitable for IO bound tasks.  It means (most likely) that two threads is optimal for your code, not ten.*

Comment: But it is not really optimal. Sometimes, I do know better, and need to directly control the number of threads instead of relying on some heuristic in PLINQ.

Comment: I suspect that the code you are using for testing really does perform optimally with two threads, and that, were there true I/O blocking in your test code, that PLinq would open up more threads.

Comment: Hmm, I underestimated the heuristics. It changes the number of threads after a few complete iterations.