# Change Parallel.ForEach MaxDegreeOfParallelism while running?

Tags: c#, multithreading, parallel.foreach

Let imagine that I have a `Parallel.ForEach` running in my code with the `ParallelOption` `MaxDegreeOfParallelism` set to `Utils.Threads()` like that :

```
Parallel.ForEach(linesList, new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = Utils.Threads() }, line => ...
```

Now imagine that `Utils.Threads()` is returning a random integer between 1 and 10.

Will the `MaxDegreeOfParallelism` change while my `Parallel.ForEach` is running, or will it be set to the first `Utils.Threads()` call for all the time ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm venturing a guess that you can't modify this once it's initialized. I read the msdn page and couldn't find anything mentioning you could (or couldn't), but I'd err on the side that you can't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Will the MaxDegreeOfParallelism change while my Parallel.ForEach is running, or will it be set to the first Utils.Threads() call for all the time ? Thanks in advance.

No it wouldn't, since it doesn't keep checking and modifying the assigned value, which is required during API initialization. Infact if you review the signature of `MaxDegreeOfParallelism`,

```
public int MaxDegreeOfParallelism { get; set; }
```

since its a value type not a reference type, its `integer`, so in any case, value is copied it is never referred for any change in value, standard behavior of the value types

> Impact of `MaxDegreeOfParallelism` on `Parallel.ForEach` call

Its an indicator or the hint, it doesn't ensure that many parallel threads are provisioned from the pool before execution starts. For `Parallel.ForEach` it always starts with single thread and keep appending the ability to execute in parallel depending upon the number of tasks and amount of time they take.
This value is also internally moderated, its not that you can provide a very high value and expect that many threads to be provisioned. It though behaves differently in case of `PLinq`, where before processing it would expect most of threads to be provisioned / initialized, but it can have an adverse performance impact, if there's not enough work for each thread, due to context switching

Couple of reference links, regarding DOP in C# Parallel / PLinq API:

[When to set the max degree of parallelism](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/7491b981-10a6-48b3-af6a-7f6b8d618fd1/when-to-set-the-max-degree-of-parallelism?forum=parallelextensions)

[Max Degree of Parallelism for AsParallel()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25290389/max-degree-of-parallelism-for-asparallel)

Comment: Very nice answer, helped me understanding it a lot more better ! Since you seem pretty good about this subject, is there an other way than Parallel.ForEach to do the same thing I'm doing actually with my list ? Thanks !

Comment: Welcome, another important point, since `MaxDegreeOfParallelism`, is a value type, `int`, so in any case value is copied once it cannot be referred back for any change, that can happen only for reference type